# Count Data In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I want to count data based on status in Laravel 5.7. I have six status (Assigned, On The Way, Started, Cancel Worker, Cancel Admin and Closed). I have to make a query for this inside foreach data.

This is my code:

```
  $data['list_detail'] = [];

  foreach ($listFa as $value) {
    $type = $value->type;
    $descr = $value->descr;

    $c_ass_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('status','like','%Assigned%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $c_otw_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('assign_status','like','%On The Way%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $c_str_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('assign_status','like','%Started%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $c_cbw_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('assign_status','like','%Cancel Worker%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $c_cba_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('assign_status','like','%Cancel Admin%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $c_cls_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)
                                ->where('assign_status','like','%Closed%')
                                ->groupBy('type')
                                ->count();

    $total = $c_ass_detail +  $c_otw_detail +  $c_str_detail +  $c_cbw_detail + $c_cba_detail + $c_cls_detail;                         

    array_push($data['list_detail'], array('type'=>$type, 'descr'=>$descr, 'c_ass_detail'=>$c_ass_detail, 'c_otw_detail'=>$c_otw_detail, 'c_str_detail'=>$c_str_detail, 'c_cbw_detail'=>$c_cbw_detail, 'c_cba_detail'=>$c_cba_detail, 'c_cls_detail'=>$c_cls_detail, 'total'=>$total));
  }
```

and this is my view code:

```
   <tbody>
       @foreach($list_detail_fa as $row)
      <tr class="tr_dashboard">
          <td>{{ $row['fa_type_cd'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['descr'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_ass_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_otw_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_str_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_cbw_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_cba_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['c_cls_detail'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $row['total'] }}</td>
      </tr>
       @endforeach                    
   </tbody>
```

It's working, but I think this way is not good because when I refresh the page, it's so slow to show back the data. Maybe it's because to many same queries. So how to good way, if I want to count the data just using one query for each status

Comment: I believe, you should groupby `assign_status`. And you can use single query, like `$c_otw_detail = transaction::where('type', $value->type)->groupBy('assign_status')->count();`

Comment: how do i put `assign_status `value? in array like this `assign_status=['status1','status2',etc]` ?

Comment: Why do you want to have where clause on `assign_status`? Did you tried the query that I commented above?

Comment: because i have 6 type status for assign_status, so i use where clause on assign_status to check the type status one by one

Comment: i have update my answer, try it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregate function `count` within your query with group by. Assuming your table name is transactions. Try this!

```
$typeCounts = DB::table('transactions')
              ->select('type', 'assign_status', DB::raw('count(type) as type_count'))
              ->where('type', $value->type)
              ->groupBy('assign_status')
              ->get();
```

And then in twig you can access it like this:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr class="tr_dashboard">
         @foreach($typeCounts as $row)
          <td>{{ $row['type_count'] }}</td>
        @endforeach    
      </tr>                  
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating things for yourself:

You simply need:

```
$allTypes = array_map(function ($value) {
           return $value->type;
}, $listFa);

 $c_ass_detail = transaction::whereIn('type', $allTypes)
                            ->groupBy('type')
                            ->groupBy('assign_status')
                            ->select('type', 'assign_status', \DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                            ->get();
```

Then your `$c_ass_detail` will have a row for each type, assign status, count combination.